# Magento 2 Override by preference not working

Tags: magento, model, overriding, magento2, preference

Everything seems right but my overriding is not working

Trying to override a Model from
`vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/ProductUrlPathGenerator.php`

Path for di.xml `app/code/Rltsquare/Customrewrite/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator" type="Rltsquare\Customrewrite\Model\CatalogUrlRewrite\ProductUrlPathGenerator" />
</config>
```

Path for Model file after overriding
`app/code/Rltsquare/Customrewrite/Model/CatalogUrlRewrite/ProductUrlPathGenerator.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Rltsquare\Customrewrite\Model\CatalogUrlRewrite;

use Magento\Store\Model\Store;

class ProductUrlPathGenerator extends \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator
{

    protected function prepareProductUrlKey(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $urlKey = $product->getUrlKey();
        return 'products/'.$product->formatUrlKey($urlKey === '' || $urlKey === null ? $product->getName() : $urlKey);
    }

}
```

Do i have to compile or run any other command after this type of overriding (preference)

Comment: any error you get in system.log file?

Comment: Try this command `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` or try to delete `var/generation` folder